# 結果発表！新年のアルゴリズム キャンペーン (2019年)

Tags: サポート, キャンペーン

アルゴリズムキャンペーンにご参加いただき、誠にありがとうございました！

---

新年といえば[アルゴリズム](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%82%a2%e3%83%ab%e3%82%b4%e3%83%aa%e3%82%ba%e3%83%a0)というわけで、新年の[アルゴリズム](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%82%a2%e3%83%ab%e3%82%b4%e3%83%aa%e3%82%ba%e3%83%a0)タグの投稿キャンペーンを行いますのでふるってご参加ください！

ルールは非常に簡単です: [アルゴリズム](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%82%a2%e3%83%ab%e3%82%b4%e3%83%aa%e3%82%ba%e3%83%a0)タグを付けて**質問**するか、それらの質問に**回答**するだけです。

#### 詳細

このキャンペーンは2019年1月1日から2019年1月31日までに投稿される[アルゴリズム](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%82%a2%e3%83%ab%e3%82%b4%e3%83%aa%e3%82%ba%e3%83%a0)タグの付いた質問や回答が全て対象となります。（UTC時間）

*<sub>回答の作成日時が考慮されます。つまり各セッションが終わる前に回答が投稿された場合にはその回答も結果の計算に含まれます。</sub>

#### Winnerの選定

1. 期間中に最も多くの投票を得た質問の投稿者
2. 期間中に最も多くの投票を得た回答の投稿者
3. 期間中に自己回答し、その回答が他の回答よりも多くの投票を得た場合の投稿者
4. 期間中に最も多くの投票を得た承認済みの回答を投稿したユーザー
5. 期間中に最も多くの回答を得た質問を投稿したユーザー
6. 期間中に最も多く閲覧された質問を投稿したユーザー
7. 期間中に最も多く質問を投稿したユーザー
8. 期間中に最も多く回答を投稿したユーザー

同じ条件を満たす場合は最も多くの投票を得たものや、より早く投稿されたものを選ぶこととします。キャンペーンは二つのセッションに分けて開催されます。

- *第一セッション*: 2019年1月1日から1月10日まで
- *第二セッション*: 2019年1月11日から1月31日まで

各セッションでWinnerが選ばれますが、賞品は一人につき一つとなります。例えば、両セッションの同じカテゴリーでWinnerに二度選ばれたり、いくつかのカテゴリーでWinnerに選ばれたとしても、受け取れる賞品は一つとなります。

#### 賞品

最も素晴らしい賞品といえば知識ですが、知識や達成感の他にちょっと素敵な賞品を準備しております！

こちらのスタック・オーバーフローオリジナル風呂敷はお選びいただける賞品のうちの一つです♬
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 年明けの2019年1月1日に開始しましょう!

誰か[アルゴリズム](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%82%a2%e3%83%ab%e3%82%b4%e3%83%aa%e3%82%ba%e3%83%a0)の質問をできる人を知っていますか？すぐに招待してください！回答してくれる人も？どうぞその人も招待してください！

[アルゴリズム](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%82%a2%e3%83%ab%e3%82%b4%e3%83%aa%e3%82%ba%e3%83%a0)タグのついたあなたの質問や回答をお待ちしております。是非この機会に[アルゴリズム](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%82%a2%e3%83%ab%e3%82%b4%e3%83%aa%e3%82%ba%e3%83%a0)タグをウォッチしてくださいね！頑張ってください！

**重要**: 結果発表は投票を得る機会を増やすため各セッションの10日後に行います。

---

#### Winnerの選定方法

[SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/)で以下のクエリを実行することで確認できます

1. 期間中に最も多くの投票を得た質問の投稿者

   ```
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, p.Id, p.Title, p.Score 
   From Posts p 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = p.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 1715 AND p.PostTypeId = 1 AND p.CreationDate >= '2019-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2019-01-11' 
   ORDER BY p.Score desc;
   ```
2. 期間中に最も多くの投票を得た回答の投稿者

   ```
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, p.Id, parent.Title, p.Score
   From Posts p 
     Join Posts parent on parent.Id = p.ParentId 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = parent.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 1715 AND p.PostTypeId = 2 AND p.CreationDate >= '2019-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2019-01-11' 
   ORDER BY p.Score desc;
   ```
3. 期間中に自己回答し、その回答が他の回答よりも多くの投票を得た投稿者(このクエリは自己回答用)

   ```
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, p.Id, parent.Title, p.Score
   From Posts p 
     Join Posts parent on parent.Id = p.ParentId 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = parent.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 1715 AND p.PostTypeId = 2 AND p.OwnerUserId = parent.OwnerUserId AND p.CreationDate >= '2019-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2019-01-11' 
   ORDER BY p.Score desc;
   ```
4. 期間中に最も多くの投票を得た承認済みの回答を投稿したユーザー（コメントより -> 自己回答OKです）

   ```
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, p.Id, parent.Title, p.Score
   From Posts p 
     Join Posts parent on parent.Id = p.ParentId 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = parent.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 1715 AND p.PostTypeId = 2 AND p.Id = parent.AcceptedAnswerId AND p.CreationDate >= '2019-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2019-01-11' 
   ORDER BY p.Score desc;
   ```
5. 期間中に最も多くの回答を得た質問を投稿したユーザー

   ```
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, p.Id, p.Title, p.AnswerCount, p.Score  
   From Posts p 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = p.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 1715 AND p.PostTypeId = 1 AND p.CreationDate >= '2019-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2019-01-11' 
   ORDER BY p.AnswerCount desc, p.Score desc;
   ```
6. 期間中に最も多く閲覧された質問を投稿したユーザー

   ```
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, p.Id, p.Title, m.ViewCount, p.Score 
   From Posts p 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = p.Id 
     Join PostMetadata m on m.PostId = p.Id
   Where t.TagId = 1715 AND p.PostTypeId = 1 AND p.CreationDate >= '2019-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2019-01-11' 
   ORDER BY m.ViewCount desc, p.Score desc;
   ```
7. 期間中に最も多く質問を投稿したユーザー

   ```
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, COUNT (DISTINCT p.Id) AS Number
   From Posts p 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = p.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 1715 AND p.PostTypeId = 1 AND p.CreationDate >= '2019-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2019-01-11' 
   GROUP BY p.OwnerUserId
   ORDER BY Number desc;
   ```
8. 期間中に最も多く回答を投稿したユーザー

   ```
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, COUNT(DISTINCT p.Id) AS Number
   From Posts p 
     Join Posts parent on parent.Id = p.ParentId 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = parent.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 1715 AND p.PostTypeId = 2 AND p.CreationDate >= '2019-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2019-01-11' 
   GROUP BY p.OwnerUserId
   ORDER BY Number desc;
   ```

Comment: 「期間中に最も多くの投票を得た承認済みの回答を投稿したユーザー」は、自己回答でもOKですか？

Comment: @nekketsuuu Self-answers work fine here! It's just should to be accepted.

Answer (score 7):

## 第一セッションの結果発表

私たちの中には大学時代を懐かしく思い出す人が多くいるかもしれません。離散数学やアルゴリズム理論、プログラミングなどを、どのように学びましたか？職場では、ソートや要素の検索、順列といった学術的なものが欠けていることが多いように思います。 [アルゴリズム](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%82%a2%e3%83%ab%e3%82%b4%e3%83%aa%e3%82%ba%e3%83%a0)タグの質問は、もしかするとこのようなギャップを埋めるのに役立つかもしれません。

第一セッションの受賞者は「[ruby で ordered hash 的なことがやりたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/51687/78)」の質問者 [@Yuki Inoue](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/754/yuki-inoue)、そして「[ruby で ordered hash 的なことがやりたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/51696/78)」と「[幅優先探索を、キューを使わずに再帰関数を使って実装することはできるのでしょうか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/51722/78)」の回答者 [@ポジティブうざいリグルちゃん](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/31654/)でした。おめでとうございます！

第二セッションは1月31日まで開催されています。是非この機会に[アルゴリズム](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%82%a2%e3%83%ab%e3%82%b4%e3%83%aa%e3%82%ba%e3%83%a0) タグをつけて質問や回答を投稿してくださいね！

---

A lot of thanks to [@aki](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/14055/aki) for the translation!
(and thanks [@nekketsuuu](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/19110/nekketsuuu) for noticing.., it is [アルゴリズム](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%82%a2%e3%83%ab%e3%82%b4%e3%83%aa%e3%82%ba%e3%83%a0) タグ m_ _m)

Comment: Winnerの @ポジティブうざいリグルちゃん さんへ：スタック・オーバーフローアカウントに紐づいているメールアドレスをご確認いただけましたでしょうか？賞品送付についてのメールはそちらにお送りしてありますのでご返信いただけましたら幸いですm_ _m

Answer (score 4):

A lot of thanks to [@aki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/14055/aki) for the translation.

---

### 第二セッションの結果発表

第二セッションではアクティビティーが活発になりました！たくさんのユーザーのみなさまに参加いただき嬉しく思います。私たちはどうやらアルゴリズムが好きなようです。

第二セッションの受賞者は次の４名です。おめでとうございます！

#### 最も多くの投票と回答を得た、そして最も多く閲覧された質問の投稿者

[@komatsuna](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/31930/komatsuna) の「[クイックソートの2種類の実装法で実行速度に顕著な違いが出る](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/52329/78)」 の質問は
12のプラス票、4つの回答が付き、452回の閲覧がありました。

#### 最も多くの投票を得た承認済みの回答を投稿したユーザー

[@zakki](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/241/zakki) の「[クイックソートの2種類の実装法で実行速度に顕著な違いが出る](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/52329/78)」の回答は11のプラス票、そしてバウンティ50点を獲得しました。

#### 自己回答し他の回答よりも多くの投票を得た投稿者

[@nekketsuuu](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/19110/nekketsuuu)の 自己回答「[Git の 3-way merge とは具体的にどのようなアルゴリズムですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/52019/78)」の質問は5のプラス票、そして回答には4のプラス票を獲得しました。

#### 最も多く質問を投稿したユーザー

[@nekketsuuu](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/19110/nekketsuuu) は7つの質問を投稿し、それらには合計26のプラス票と6つの回答が付きました。

#### 最も多く回答を投稿したユーザー

[@yohjp](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/49/yohjp) は2つの質問に回答し合計5のプラス票を獲得しました。

みなさま、おめでとうございます！

Comment: Winnerの @zakki さんへ：スタック・オーバーフローアカウントに紐づいているメールアドレスをご確認いただけましたでしょうか？賞品送付についてのメールはそちらにお送りしてありますのでご返信いただけましたら幸いですm_ _m