# スタック・オーバーフローの正式版一周年記念をお祝いしましょう！

Tags: 討議

翻訳をしてくれた[@aki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/14055/aki)に感謝します。

---

[正式版一周年アニバーサリーイベント](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3813/14055)を迎えられることを本当に嬉しく思います。スタック・オーバーフロー日本語版は、Stack Exchange ネットワーク全体で最もオーセンティックなイベントコミュニティなのではないでしょうか。

スタック・オーバーフローのプライベート Beta 版は 2014 年 9 月に開設され、12 月にパブリック Beta 版が公開されました。コミュニティがメインサイトでプログラミングに関する質問と回答を始め、コミュニティ自体に興味を持った人々がサイトの設定に関する様々な作業を開始しました。[ヘルプセンターを更新し](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%83%98%e3%83%ab%e3%83%97)、[専門用語を統一し](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11/) そして [スタック・オーバーフロー日本語版が Stack Overflow 英語版とどのように共存できるかを議論しました](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257/)。（2014 年以降、メタでは 1000 を超える異なるトピックについて議論を行なってきました！） [翻訳](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e7%bf%bb%e8%a8%b3) もたくさんの人々が協力し合いやってきました。

もともと、Stack Overflow 英語版は多言語化をサポートできるようには設計されていませんでした。SO 多言語版サイトと協力して、英語を母国語としないユーザーにとって UI がわかりやすいように懸命に取り組んできました。

スタック・オーバーフローではこれまでたくさんの [オフライン / オンラインイベント](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e4%ba%a4%e6%b5%81%e4%bc%9a) を開催してきました。

例えば：

- [5/31(金)東京・渋谷でMeetUpを開催します　→　しました！](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2982/)
- [秋のコンテスト開催中：あなたの質問にまつわる裏話を教えてください！](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3075/)
- [結果発表！新年のアルゴリズム キャンペーン (2019年)](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2903/)

（個人的には [もくもく会イベント](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%82%82%e3%81%8f%e3%82%82%e3%81%8f%e4%bc%9a) がぼくのお気に入りです。[nekketsuuu](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/19110/nekketsuuu)、[ento](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/30/ento)、そして [payaneco](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/9820/payaneco) が主導してくださいました。）

これらは、私たちが一緒に作ったクールなもののほんの一部です。

今日は大事な日です。コミュニティの Beta 版卒業と一周年記念を祝っています。質問や回答をしてくれた人、コンテンツをキュレートした人、サイトをモデレートした人、そしてこの旅に参加してくれたすべての人に感謝したいと思います。これはゴールではなく始まりです。

[payaneco](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/9820/payaneco) のライトニングトークイベントを楽しみつつ、みなさんもぜひこちらの回答欄に共有してください。

***スタック・オーバーフローコミュニティの歴史の中で最も記憶に残っている瞬間は？***

改めまして、おめでとうございます。皆様のご多幸をお祈り申し上げます！

Answer (score 7):

ニコラスさんが送ってくださった(日本語の！)短いイントロ動画を見て、イベント参加者はとても喜んでいました。
The event attendees were very pleased with the short intro video(Japanese Greetings!) you sent us.

積極的にイベントを盛り上げてくださったので、無事にイベントを実施することができました。ありがとうございました！
You actively promoted the event and made sure it went off without a hitch. Thank you very much!

---

#### スタック・オーバーフローコミュニティの歴史の中で最も記憶に残っている瞬間は？

[渋谷でのSOja MeetUp](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2982/9820)が最も記憶に残っています。
実際に[ロボットではない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/115/not-a-robot)方々と、掲示板でやり取りしているのだと実感し、嬉しく思いました。
ご時世で難しいところもありますが、対面でのイベントはオンラインと違う楽しさがあるのでまたいつか開催されることを願っております。

と、一昨日までの自分は答えたことでしょう。
今の私にとって最も記憶に残っている瞬間は、[正式版1周年記念Webミーティング](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3813/9820)が始まって、録画スタートし忘れたことに気づいた瞬間(開始4分後あたり)です。
「やらかしたー！」と頭が真っ白になった後はテンパりすぎて何を話したか記憶が定かではありません。

そのため、ニコラスさんの動画が流れている時の共有画面やコメントの保存に失敗してしまいました。
大変申し訳ございません。
As a result, I failed to save the sharing screen and comments when Nicholas' video was playing.
I'm very sorry.

今後、同じようなオンラインイベントを開催させる方におかれましては、同様のことが起こらないように「録画！！」と書いた大きな付箋をご用意いただくか、穴があったら入れるようにシャベルをご用意いただくことをお勧めします。

Answer (score 5):

コミュニティをリードくださった人々、つまりモデレーターのみなさんに特別な感謝を述べたいと思います。感謝を伝えたい人は、どうかこちらにプラス票をよろしくお願いします！

#### ベータ版公開時に多大な貢献をいただいた初代モデレーターのみなさん

**entoさん**
[image: ento]

**unarist さん**
[image: unarist]

**tomute さん**
[image: tomute]

#### 現在もコミュニティを守りリードくださるモデレーターのみなさん

**Yuki Inoue さん**
[image: Yuki Inoue]

**nekketsuuu さん**
[image: nekketsuuu]

**cubick さん**
[image: cubick]

Answer (score 4):

客観的なデータでも振り返ってみようということで、 https://archive.org/details/stackexchange から取得できる (全期間の) ダンプデータを元に、可能な範囲で分析してみます。(2022/12/05 時点のデータ)
気が向いたら後から他にも追加するかもしれません。

#### 信用度の分布:

[権限](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges?tab=all) のマイルストーンと照らし合わせながら、信用度の分布図を作成してみました。

- 信用度 `1` な作成しっ放し、または英語なスパムが意外と多いです。
- 信用度 `4000` = "信頼できるユーザー" 以上がまだまだ少ないかなという印象 (プラス投票やっぱり大事)

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 年度別のアカウント作成数:

- 2017年に跳ねてるのは何かきっかけがありましたっけ…？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 3):

振り返ると記憶に残っている瞬間がたくさんあるので、ご活躍されているみなさんをご紹介させてください‍♀️！

#### 信用度ランキング（全期間）

**sayuri さん**
[image: sayuri]

**nekketsuuu さん**
[image: nekketsuuu]

**774RR さん**
[image: 774RR]

#### メインサイトのトップ編集者（全期間）

**cubick さん**
[image: cubick]

**nekketsuuu さん**
[image: nekketsuuu]

**supa さん**
[image: supa]

#### メインサイトのトップ投票者（全期間）

**nekketsuuu さん**
[image: nekketsuuu]

**Yuki Inoue さん**
[image: Yuki Inoue]

**supa さん**
[image: supa]

#### メインサイトのトップ投票者（2022年度）

**qwj-38 さん**
[image: qwj-38]

**kunif さん**
[image: kunif]

**wtsnjp さん**
[image: wtsnjp]

#### メタサイトのトップ投票者（全期間）

**aterai さん**
[image: aterai]

**伽語蓮弥 さん**
[image: aterai]

**yohjp さん**
[image: yohjp]

#### 「初めての質問」のトップレビュアー（全期間）

**supa さん**
[image: supa]

**keitaro-so さん**
[image: keitaro-so]

**qwj-38 さん**
[image: qwj-38]

#### LTイベント（2022/12/17）

このたび大変お忙しい中イベントを推し進めてくださった payaneco さんに、心からお礼申し上げます。そして、いつもコミュニティ全体をみてくださる nekketsuuu さんにも感謝の気持ちでいっぱいです。

**payaneco さん**
[image: payaneco]

**nekketsuuu さん**
[image: nekketsuuu]

誰か一人の力ではコミュニティは成り立ちません。スタック・オーバーフローに善意を持って参加くださっていたならば、もしそれがほんの少しだとしてもそのコントリビューションはこのプラットフォームで生きていますし、そしてこれからも生き続けるのでしょう。

スタック・オーバーフローをこれからもどうぞよろしくお願いいたします！